# simultaneous pi camera threads C code

Tags: raspicam

I have used motioneyeos in the past to implement a motion capture video recording system on a raspberry pi, right out of the "box". It was nice in that it could do motion detection, video recording, and a live http webcam server simultaneously. However, the motion detection wasn't quite good enough for my situation (I was getting tons of false alarms), so I decided to take a stab at my own motion detection algorithms that are custom tailored to my environment.

I managed to use [videoci](https://github.com/zontarian/cameraci) to stream raw RGB pixel buffers from the camera into C code so I could develop my motion detection algorithm. I then called 'raspivid' directly to record mp4 video clips from the camera. Finally, I got 'uv4l' working which allowed a live http webcam server.

The problem is that I can only do one of these tasks at a time. It seems there is a resource sharing problem once the camera is activated.

Is there a way to allow these tasks to be run simultaneously? If not, is there a better approach that would make it possible? I'd prefer to keep my algorithm in C/C++, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have `v4l2loopback` kernel module (if not, build it from [sources](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)). Then feed the video from the actual camera into the loopback device (using Gstreamer, FFmpeg, etc.), and read it back in the applications you intended to run simultaneously. [Here](https://github.com/your-diary/v4l2_webcam)'s a sample script providing handy wrapper functions. Then you could do something like this:

[image: example_structure]

`v4l2loopback` developers seem to provide support on [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v4l2loopback).